# How to pass components dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend

I am building a rock/paper/scissors React app, but I am having problems when I try to make a choice (rock, scissors or paper), save the value of that choice and display it in the screen.
I have managed to console.log all the values of the user selected choice, but I don't know how to pass them back to my Choice component, and actually see it on the screen.

Could you please help me resolving this issue ?

Thanks a lot!

Main.js

```
import React from "react"
import Choice from "./Choice"

import paper from '../images/icon-paper.svg'
import rock from '../images/icon-rock.svg'
import scissors from '../images/icon-scissors.svg'

import './Main.css';

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            onScreen: true,
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            onScreen: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/*HOME PAGE*/}
                <div className="main-container" style={{display: (this.state.onScreen ? "block" : "none")}}>
                    <div className="triangle-container">
                        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice
                                name="paper"
                                image={paper} 
                                borderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 62%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 65%)"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice
                                name="scissors"
                                image={scissors} 
                                borderColor="hsl(39, 89%, 49%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(40, 84%, 53%)"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{gridArea: "bottom"}} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice 
                                name="rock"
                                image={rock} 
                                borderColor="hsl(349, 71%, 52%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(349, 70%, 56%)"
                            />
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/*RESULT PAGE*/}
                <div className="rsult-container" style={{display: (!this.state.onScreen ? "block" : "none")}}>
                    <Choice />
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

Choice.js

```
import React from "react"

import './Choice.css';

class Choice extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: props.name,
            image: props.image,
            borderColor: props.borderColor,
            extraBorderColor: props.extraBorderColor
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log(this.state.name)
        console.log(this.state.image)
        console.log(this.state.borderColor)
        console.log(this.state.extraBorderColor)
        
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="elem-box">
                <div 
                    style={{borderColor: this.state.borderColor, color: this.state.extraBorderColor}} 
                    className="elem-container"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                    <img src={this.props.image} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Choice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new property in `Main` component's state (let's call it `choiceName`).

```
this.state = {
  onScreen: true,
  choiceName: '',
}
```

Update your `Main` component's `handleClick` into a curry function:

```
handleClick = (choiceName) => () => {
  this.setState({
    onScreen: false,
    choiceName,
  });
}
```

Then send in `handleClick` to `Choice` component as props:

```
<Choice
  name="paper"
  image={paper}
  borderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 62%)"
  extraBorderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 65%)"
  handleClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```

Update your `Choice` component by removing its `handleClick` definition and changing the `render` method to below:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="elem-box">
      <div
        style={{ borderColor: this.state.borderColor, color: this.state.extraBorderColor }}
        className="elem-container"
        onClick={this.handleClick(this.state.name)}
      >
        <img src={this.props.image} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And finally use the `this.state.choiceName` value to display in the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But doing so if I click on my choice what is displayed is the name. Instead I would like to display the whole element (image, border, extraborder)

Comment: Just update params of `handleClick` to receive the needed values and then use them in `setState` call.

Answer (score 0):

To render the full result;

Move the individual images into an object called images:

```
const images = {
  paper,
  rock,
  scissors
}
```

Then update the result **Choice** to use the name from state, and give it a borderColor:

```js
{/*RESULT PAGE*/}
<div className="result-container" style={{display: (!this.state.onScreen ? "block" : "none")}}>
  <Choice 
    name={this.state.choiceName}
    image={images[this.state.choiceName]} 
    borderColor="hsl(349, 71%, 52%)" 
    extraBorderColor="hsl(349, 70%, 56%)"
  />
</div>
```